# "Gleis" or "Bahnsteig"?

Tags: word-usage

If I understand correctly, at a railway station *Gleis* designates the (rail)track while *Bahnsteig* is the platform.

When giving information about where to go to catch a train, do we usually refer to the *Gleis* (which is actually where the train is) or to the *Bahnsteig* (like it is done in English)?

Are there regional differences? (I mean between Hochdeutsch, Austrian German, Swiss German...)

Comment: In Swiss-German you use "Perron" oder "Kante" but Bahnsteig.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has a unique usage, there is not regional difference.

Actually, it's just a logical problem. *Gleis* (rail track) is where the train approaches, *Bahnsteig* (platform) is where the people are waiting.

A train can approach *am Bahnsteig 3* or *auf Gleis 3*, pay attention to *am* and *auf*; *am* means alongside the platform, *auf* means it goes on the rail track. The station announcement can use both versions, it doesn't matter, both ones are correct. They just should use the proper preposition to hold back people from entering the rail track or prevent the train to jump on the platform, respectively. ;)

Examples to check:

- "Der Zug hat Einfahrt auf Gleis 3!" vs. "Der Zug hat Einfahrt am Bahnsteig 3!"
- Note "Bitte begeben Sie sich zum Bahnsteig 3, der Zug hat Einfahrt auf Gleis 2!" could be used, if platform 2 is closed because of a a building lot and platform 3 is alongside rail track 2 also.
- *zu* is possible with "Bahnsteig" and "Gleis"; the announcement "Bitte begeben Sie sich zu Gleis 3" expects you know what to do in that case, and you can choose the platform by yourself

Comment: „Der Zug hat Einfahrt“? Do they really say that?

Comment: @Carsten Schultz: na klar, ist doch offizielle Ansagensprache der Bahn, zumindest als ich noch damit gefahren bin. Findet man auch tausendfach im Internet.

Comment: Sieh an, muss ich mal drauf achten.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Sie sagen es tatsächlich. An der Richtigkeit zweifle ich.

Comment: Genauso wie "Dieser Zug endet hier" :D Na ja, man sollte Deutsch halt nicht von den Durchsagen der Bahn lernen :))

Comment: @Stan: Ursprünglich ist _Zug_ nicht das Transportmittel, sondern die Bewegung. _Der Zug dieser Vögel endet in Afrika._

Comment: @chirlu: danke, wieder was dazu gelernt!

Comment: (OT:) Fortgeschrittene erklären bitte die Bahnsteigfolge am Bahnhof Potsdam: http://demystifikation.wordpress.com/2013/08/09/unschuldige-beobachtung-am-bahnhof-potsdam/

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I also heard `Am Gleis 1 erhält Einfahrt..`

Comment: @embert `Auf Gleis x erhält Einfahrt` is very common and means that all signals and junctions are set so that the train will now enter (= einfahren) the station on track x without having to yield to other trains anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I would say both are fine colloquially.

But if you want to give travel information to someone, I would prefer using:

> Gleis

You can see this on every travel information page from the [Deutsche Bahn](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de) or similar services. They always refer to a "*Gleis*" instead of a "*Bahnsteig*".

Answer (score 0):

> When giving information about where to go to catch a train, do we usually refer to the Gleis (which is actually where the train is) or to the Bahnsteig (like it is done in English)?

Additionally to falkb: Both terms are used.

It's *always* the tracks (***Gleise***) which are numbered and *never* the platforms (***Bahnsteige***). However, the platform next to a certain track might be referred to with the track number.

For instance ***Am Bahnsteig 1*** and ***Am Bahnsteig 2*** can denote the same platform with two tracks (one on each side).